# ASPX - Why is the parameterless constructor invoked, skipping the parameterized one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

This is the http request of browser

```
http://localhost:59440/CaseCards/Registrai/neigaliuju_registras.aspx?saliesId=5b8c3abc-4eec-4d69-b66a-25c7f27a2187
```

This is my code-behind file with two constructors

```
public NeigaliujuRegistras()
{

}

public NeigaliujuRegistras(string saliesId)
{
     _saliesId = new Guid(saliesId);
     //more of very secret bla bla
}
```

The following code makes the request

```
oWnd = radopen("CaseCards/Registrai/neigaliuju_registras.aspx?saliesId=" + $("input[name*='hsvSaliesId']").val(), "meow");
```

If I put breakpoints on both constructors, I see that upon laoding it goes into parameterless constructor, and the parametered one is never invoked.

This results in `_saliesID` having `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}` value.

**Why is the parameterless constructor invoked over parameterized one?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way how the ASP .Net framework creates these instances.

In your particular case you don't need this constructor since you can get the saliesId from `Request.QueryString` object. If you still want to have this in the constructor you can do something like this.

```
public NeigaliujuRegistras()
{
    // attach a handler to the Init event so to make sure the Request object is available.
    this.Init += (_o, _e) => {
         saliesId = new Guid(Request.QueryString["saliesId"]);
    };
}
```

Or you can follow the standard way placing the code in the Page_Load method.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    saliesId = new Guid(Request.QueryString["saliesId"]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Adrian, I didn't know I had to parse parameters manually.
I thought it worked the same way as ASP.NET MVC where framework would parse the parameters and choose the matching constructor.

Comment: Welcome! Neither ASP .Net MVC does it this way. ASP .Net MVC does this mapping in the other methods (controllers actions). You can define though a constructor where you can inject dependencies.